# Bayesian image classification with Keras

Tags: python, keras, bayesian-networks

I want to know how I can build a Bayesian image classification model with Keras.

By Bayesian I mean a Keras model capable of calculating **Aleatoric uncertaint**y & **Epistemic uncertainty**. I have already came across this blog post [Building a Bayesian deep learning classifier](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-bayesian-deep-learning-classifier-ece1845bc09), but I am confused. Is there any other simple example for that sort of image classification with Keras?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but I am making a library for Bayesian DL in Keras, here: https://github.com/mvaldenegro/keras-uncertainty , maybe the example you are looking for is similar to this one that uses Deep Ensembles: https://github.com/mvaldenegro/keras-uncertainty/blob/master/examples/cifar10_cnn_deepensemble.py